# Highlight all the words over 8 character long with a yellow background. How to do this question with only JavaScript without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have started learning JavaScript through practice exercises. I tried solving this question in the following way but it is not working!. Any leads would be appreciated.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  check = (word) => {
    if (word.length > 8) {
      word.style.color = "blue";
    } else {
      word;
    }
  }

  func = () => {
    var str = document.querySelector("#Second").innerText;
    var newt = str.trim().split(' ').map(check).join(' ');
    document.querySelector("#Second").innerText = newt;

  }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to set a colour on word, but word is just a string. You'll need to replace that string in the text with e.g. a span that introduces the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem lies in the `check()` function. You have analyzed the problem correctly, but you don't understand about DOM so you have done it wrong way.

First, the word you check is pure string (which is an array of char, so that you could check it with `length` property).
Second,  the `.style.color` is child object of Element DOM object only. String cannot do that.

Because of the problem, you have to convert the string you just check to Element DOM object. Depending on cases, there is many way to do so. I will assume that the output will be like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += word
```

If that is the case, you can be at ease. Just simply wrap the `word` in this html code string. The rest you have solved it well.

(I know you use innerText, but I think innerHTML is much easier so I choose it. If you really need to use innerText, comment below and I will update the post)

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const check = word => {
    if (word.length > 8) {
      return '<span class="hightlight">' + word + '</span>'
    } else {
      return word
    }
  }

  const sample = document.querySelector("#sample")
  sample.innerHTML = sample
    .innerText
    .trim()
    .split(' ')
    .map(check)
    .join(' ')
}
```

```css
#sample {}

.hightlight {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<p id='sample'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

My advice. Before doing anything, try to understand the variables' type you are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have a question. Why the above code is not working, if I change sample.innerHTML to sample.innerText? What's the difference?  I know that innerHTML includes the tags as string text but in the above case, both innerHTML and innerText should work fine as there ain't any child tags in <p>. Right?

Comment: Even textContent property is not working. why the only innerHTML is working?

Comment: innerText is the plain text content of the element. <span>...</span> is HTML, so it's removed.

Comment: @SaraSameer In short, `innerText` only accept plain string while `innerHTML` will likely convert (parse) the HTML format string to a really HTML that browser can render. I would recommend you to study MDN about [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) for deeper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  check = (word) => {
    if (word.length > 8) {
      word = '<span style="background:yellow;">' + word + '</span>';
    } else {
      word;
    }
    return word;
  }

  var str = document.querySelector("#Second").innerText;
  var newt = str.trim().split(' ').map(check).join(' ');
  document.querySelector("#Second").innerHTML = newt;

}
```

```html
<div id="Second">Short short thiswordislong short short thiswordislongtoo short</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Can you please elaborate on the following part of code.       if (word.length > 8) {
      word = '<span style="color:blue;">' + word + '</span>';
    } else {
      word;
    }
    return word;

Comment: Your're passing a string into the check function, as such it's not a DOM element and you can't apply any style to it. So, you need to wrap the word in an element (I chose a span) so you can then apply the style.

Comment: So it's not mandatory to use span right? I have seen the use of span for styling a lot? This is not any rule, right?

Comment: That's right, you can use any element. Span is good because it's an inline element, so by default doesn't disrupt the flow of the text. If you use e.g. a DIV, it will break onto a new line (unless the stylesheet says differently)

Answer (score 0):

Version with .|,|? detection

```js
const setup = () => {
  const p = document.querySelector('p');

  wrapWordsWithLengthEight(p);
}

const check = (word) => {

  //Check if word include a .|,|?
  const hasCharacter = word.includes(".", word.length - 1)
  || word.includes(",", word.length - 1)
  || word.includes('?', word.length - 1);
  //Calculate real word length
  const wordLength = hasCharacter ? (word.length -1) : word.length;
  if(wordLength > 8) {
    const spanContent = hasCharacter ? word.substring(0, word.length - 1) : word;
    const endCharacter = hasCharacter ? (word.substring(word.length - 1)) : '';
    word = `<mark>${spanContent}</mark>${endCharacter} `;
  }
  else word = `${word} `;

  return word;
};

const wrapWordsWithLengthEight = (target) => {
  //Render HTML to target
  const text = (target.textContent).trim().split(' ').map(check).join('');
  target.innerHTML = text;
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique enim quod quos, modi architecto, praesentium tenetur suscipit assumenda, sit neque odit, illum minima voluptates? Dolor non dolore accusamus quam maiores.
</p>
```